# Why is CD/DVD tray not opening?

Tags: cd-drive

When I press the button on the dvd player, it doesn't open.

If I press it during the boot (before starting ubuntu), it opens fine.

So, what I have to do to eject the dvd?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Steps:

1. `sudo eject /dev/sr0`
2. `file /dev/sr`0
3. `sudo eject -i off`

Answer (score 1):

Some CD/DVD eject buttons send a signal, so that the operating system knows to eject. Some do not send a signal. So just pretend you do not have an ejection button on the device and use `eject` instead. If you are already on the command line...

```
eject
```

or maybe you may need to specify the device:

```
eject /dev/sdc
```

If you are not on the command line, you might use [ALT]+[F2] to run a command...
and the same commands would work that way, too.

Comment: `eject` works (I forgot to mention). Is it a wrong configuration? How to fix?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and was doing tasks with USB pendrives until now, erroneously thinking it was a software problem...but today I just used a
extended paperclip to open the CD/DVD tray using that little hole under the tray on the unit panel...after THAT the tray begun responding to commands via software or hard button...

So I think this was a hardware little lock (after moving around the pc) or
a rubber belt out of place due to wear and tear...as concluded by another contributor here in this site...

Just my experience.

Cheers and thanks.